# Dialogflow Enterprise Edition - How to use one agent against multiple chatbots?

Tags: dialogflow-es, multi-tenant

I'd like to setup a Dialogflow Enterprise edition for my multi-tenant chatbot platform.
I am looking for a documentation which describes the following:

-- How to use one dialogflow enterprise edition agent against multiple chatbots?

I get the details about session id - but session id belongs to one chatbot agent and how it can differentiate which chatbot to repond with correct intent where there are many?

If different chatbots have different conversation tracks crafted inside one Dialogflow agent, how it will differentiate the requests from each users to provide the correct conversation path (recognizing correct intents and entities without confusing with other chatbot specific conversation intents if there's near matching phrases of entities).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you should create multiple agents, one for each bot. What are you hoping to achieve by sharing one agent for all bots? You will likely end up with an overly complex single agent if you head down that path.